# How to install gitlab-runner for Ubuntu ARM host?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

1. I tried to install from package

```
sudo curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner
```

Getting

E: Unable to locate package gitlab-runner

2. Trying to download package

```
sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-arm
```

Getting 
 ERROR 403: Forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something goes wrong at the backend of gitlab.com

You can try other mirrors, e.g.: https://mirror.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/